# How to create vertical TitledBorder in JPanel (javax swing)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, titled-border

I'm trying to figure out how to create a vertical `TitledBorder` in a `JPanel`.

I've got this situation:

[image]

I'd like to have "Actuators st..." placed vertically, so user can read it.

Is there a way to do it, or should I implement my own customized `JPanel` & `TitledBorder`?

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [*How to Use Borders*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html), you can create a compound border using an empty border and a titled border.

Addendum: As an alternative, you can use the border's `getMinimumSize()` method to ensure that the title is visible. See also this related [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

[image]

```
f.add(createPanel("Actuator status"), BorderLayout.WEST);
f.add(createPanel("Indicator result"), BorderLayout.EAST);
...
private Box createPanel(String s) {
    Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, s,
        TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION);
    box.setBorder(title);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        JButton b = new JButton(null, UIManager.getIcon("html.pendingImage"));
        b.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        box.add(b);
    }
    box.validate();
    Dimension db = box.getPreferredSize();
    int max = Math.max(title.getMinimumSize(box).width, db.width);
    box.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(max, db.height));
    return box;
}
```

Comment: A more general solution is to override `getPreferredSize()`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11132778/230513).

Answer (score 2):

- maybe crazy idea but is possible with `JSeparator` too :-)
- required proper `LayoutManager`, maybe `GridBagLayout` (`JComponent` placed without `GBC` can take `PreferrredSize` from `JComponent`, but isn't resiziable), not `GridLayout`

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class NestedLayout {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    private JSeparator sep = new JSeparator();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("<html> L<br>a<br>b<br>e<br>l<br></html>");

    public NestedLayout() {
        label.setOpaque(true);
        sep.setOrientation(JSeparator.VERTICAL);
        sep.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        sep.add(new JLabel());
        sep.add(label);
        sep.add(new JLabel());
        leftPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        leftPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                10, //top
                10, //left
                10, //bottom
                10));  //right
        leftPanel.add(sep, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 220));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        //frame.add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                NestedLayout nestedLayout = new NestedLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```