# JTable in JScrollPane forces scrolling when not required

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`. If the screen shows half of a row in the `JTable`, when clicking on the `JTable`, the `JScrollPane` scrolls automatically to show the entire row.

How do I stop that behavior, such that a click will not scroll the `JScrollPane`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is enforced by calling `scrollRectToVisible()` from the table's UI delegate, typically derived from `BasicTableUI`. Short of supplying your own delegate, you can use [`setPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) to make the height of enclosing `Container` an intergral multiple of the `rowHeight`, as shown below and in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7519403/230513).

```
private static final int N_ROWS = 8;
private JTable table = new JTable();
...
Dimension d = new Dimension(
    table.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize().width,
    N_ROWS * table.getRowHeight());
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(d);
add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

[image]

Comment: you know what I think about hard-coding sizes ;-) SetPrefScrollable is not much different from any of the other setXXSize. Instead, implement the table's getPreferredScrollableViewportSize to return something reasonable, f.i. in terms of configurable properties like visible rows/columns (as JXTable does :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: Exactly right, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) and shown in this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11132778/230513).